# Parameter Paradox? (not sure how to word)

Tags: java

So I'm not sure how to word this so I'll just give an example here:

```
public class test {
    private Object1 o1;
    private Object2 o2;
    private Object3 o3;

    public test() {
        o1 = new Object1(o2, o3);
        o2 = new Object2(o1);
        o3 = new Object3(o1);
    }
}
```

So my problem is that I need to give these 3 objects parameters these ways and I get problems because when I put o2 and o3 for o1, they are null. If I try to instantiate o2 and o3 above o1, o1 is null and problems occur again. Could someone help me find a solution to this. I would also like to keep these 3 objects separate (ie. not give o2 or o3 an o1 field).

Comment: For what kind of problem you need that kind of initialize?

Comment: This is for a JFrame that needs to add 3 JPanels which interact with each other.

Comment: Create the `JPanel`s first then put the attributes in after construction. Otherwise you cannot avoid the circularity. Furthermore, your constructor names (`o1`, etc.) must match your class names (`Object1`, etc.). Also you should follow the Java naming conventions.

Comment: I think that it's not a good practice. You should descript your root problem to find out other solution instead of using these 3. But if you need a solution, I propose that you should try to use get/setter method instead of passing object via constructor.

Comment: @LewBloch Ah yes, I fixed the constructors. Overlooked it when writing this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing with [circular dependency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) 
that you need to avoid at all cost.

For your immediate need you can make constructor not to take depended objects, define set methods, create objects with empty constructor and then wire them together by passing objects to those set methods.

```
public class test { 
        private Object1 o1; 
        private Object2 o2; 
        private Object3 o3; 

        public test() { 
            o1 = new Object1(); 
            o2 = new Object2(); 
            o3 = new Object3();

            o1.setO2(o2);
            o1.setO3(o3);

            o2.setO1(o1);
            o3.setO1(o1);

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution of this problem is to use method to initiate instead of constructor.

Define methods let's say `init` & use the default constructor or no argument constructor. Now create all the objects & call the method `init` on all the objects in proper sequence.
You can do one more thing here. Let's see...
You can define constructor with two argument & define method instead of one argument constructor & call that method from the two argument constructor.
 First of all define `init` method in `Object2` & `Object3`. Constructor of `Object1`..

```
Object1(Object2 o2, Object3 o3){
    //Some code
    o2.init(this);
    o3.init(this);
    //Some code
}
```

Now your code to create objects looks like...

```
public class test { 
    private Object1 o1;
    private Object2 o2;
    private Object3 o3;
    public test() {
        o2 = new Object2();
        o3 = new Object3();
        o1 = new Object1(o2, o3);
    }
}
```